# what is a banker's bank?

Tags: banking

What is a banker's bank? I came across this term when I was scrolling through my research on banks. I came across [this](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/b/bankers-bank.asp) definition, that says that they are banks that service the charter banks that founded them(or so I understood).
I didn't know what charter was so I founded [this](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/c/charter.asp), which says charter is a legal document rather that a type of bank. The central bank(of my country), says it is a banker's bank that is supposed to actually regulate other bank's monetary policies. So, I was getting very confused with my amateur deductions and finally resolved here.

**What is a banker's bank?**

Comment: What's the context? Where did this term come up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like this is referring to a [central bank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_bank), which is a standard fixture of fiat monetary systems.

The central bank regulates the supply of money, in part by setting the terms under which retail/commercial banks can operate, borrow, and lend.